# Way to fetch all prices for all countries of all subscriptions from AppStore Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I need to track all purchase events in my iOS application.

The thing is that it uses a subscription model so the majority of events come from server-to-server notifications (sent by Apple, without the user opening the app). It can be `renew`, `cancel`, `changing the perod` etc.

In order to submit relevant prices and currency to tracking system (Appsflyer in this case), I need to know these on my server.

I came across `AppStore Connect API` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/app_prices - but it does not seem to respond with prices for different countries.

Has anyone else faced this issue? I bet there should be the ways to workaround it but still there is no too much info.